# Help me with this Validation Rule - Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Tags: validation

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(Status__c),
    (
        CASE(
            Status__c,
            "New", 1,
            "Waiting Interview", 2,
            "Interviewer Feedback Available", 3,
            "In Negotiation", 4,
            "Confirmed", 5,
            "Rejected or Cancelled", 6,
            0
        )
        <>
            CASE(
                PRIORVALUE(Status__c),
                "New", 1,
                0
            ) +1,
            CASE(
                PRIORVALUE(Status__c),
                "New", 1,
                0
            ) + 3,
            CASE(
                PRIORVALUE(Status__c),
                "New", 1,
                0
            ) + 5,
            CASE(
                PRIORVALUE(Status__c),
                "Waiting Interview", 2,
                0
            ) + 1,
            CASE(
                PRIORVALUE(Status__c),
                "Waiting Interview", 2,
                0
            ) - 1,
            CASE(
                PRIORVALUE(Status__c),
                "Waiting Interview", 2,
                0
            ) + 4,
            CASE(
                PRIORVALUE(Status__c),
                "Interviewer Feedback Available", 3,
                0
            ) + 1,
            CASE(
                PRIORVALUE(Status__c),
                "Interviewer Feedback Available", 3,
                0
            ) + 3,
            CASE(
                PRIORVALUE(Status__c),
                "In Negotiation", 4,
                0
            ) + 1,
            CASE(
                PRIORVALUE(Status__c),"In Negotiation", 4,
                0
            ) + 2
        )
    )
```

What I want to do with my formula is... :
When trying to change the Status, they must meet the numerical criteria, where I assign a number to each stage and in turn I can only change the status for those results that I want to obtain....
For example:

[image]

Comment: The first step in debugging formula fields is _always_ to format it according to best practices (i.e. like it were code). Keep separate bits of statements on separate lines, and indent an additional level every time you encounter an open parenthesis. I've applied this for you.

Comment: After doing that, it becomes quite clear where the missing `)` is, but you're also missing both an open and a close parenthesis for the `OR()`. It'll be difficult to suggest what your validation rule should actually look like unless you give us more of an explanation as to what it is you're trying to do here. It is not clear just by reading the formula in isolation. Please [edit] your question to add those additional details.

Comment: Hello Derek!
Thank you very much for the advice, I had copied it in format but it was not published that way...

What I want to do with my formula is
When trying to change the Status, they must meet the numerical criteria, where I assign a number to each stage and in turn I can only change the status for those results that I want to obtain....

Answer (score 1):

A validaiton rule *could* work for this scenario, but I think that a much better User Experience would be provided if you approached this in a different way.

### Instead of a validaiton rule, I'd suggest making a second (dependent) picklist

This new picklist would have the exact same values as your existing picklist, and you would set the existing picklist as the controlling field for it. This allows you to easily *and visually* define which picklist values (in your second, new picklist) can be chosen for a given value of the original picklist.

You would need a before-save record-triggered flow to copy the value from the second (dependent) picklist back to the first (controlling) picklist, and you would need to allow the second picklist to hold the same value as the first picklist (so "Waiting Interview" in the controlling picklist should have "Waiting Interview" allowed in the dependent picklist, along with "Interview Feedback Available" and "Rejected").

### Why is this better UX?

It's better because instead of detecting errors and asking your users to correct them, *it prevents the user from making an invalid choice altogether*. Remove the chance to fail, and your users should not fail.

I'm sure there's still some way for users to mess that up, somehow. Users are supremely skilled at breaking things in unexpected ways.

I think this approach is also easier to maintain because the determination of which transitions are allowed is represented visually rather than through a text formula with nested `CASE()`.